# Nancy 2.0.0-barneyrubble JSON retain casing

Tags: c#, .net-core, nancy

[image]Am trying to get Nancy to retain property names as they are. For example `FirstName` to remain so instead of `firstName` in `Response.AsJson`. 
I have seen where it is mentioned to set `JsonSettings.RetainCasing = true`.
I couldn't find it in `Nancy.Json` or an example where to set this configuration. Any hint where to find this setting and where to place it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Nancy uses SimpleJson.
To configure case retaining just override the configure method like this :

```
    public class MyBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
    {
        public override void Configure(INancyEnvironment environment)
        {
            environment.Json(retainCasing: true);
            base.Configure(environment);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, already done this as jchannon suggested on github. However accepting your answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

I could not make sense of the other answer, but found this solution.  Add the following line to use in your startup code.  It will prevent Nancy from converting cases on objects.

`Nancy.Json.JsonSettings.RetainCasing = true;`

I put it right before my host.Start() call:

`NancyHost host = new NancyHost(uri, new DefaultNancyBootstrapper(), hostConfigs);
 host.Start();`

Comment: Your solution is for 1.x and the answer above is for 2.x as the question already specified the version the is using.